# WordPress : Dynamically include html page in Genesis

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I have searched for an hour now and can't find my answer.  I am making a Genesis site with my own child theme.  I have a Davis Weather station that uploads the current weather every half hour.  I want to include this uploaded content on a page on my site.  I can do that by wrapping the following inside an **iframe**: `class="center-frame" src="http://localhost/tickners/wp-content/weather/current.htm" width="750" height="1100"`.  This is a development site that I will eventually take live.  The problem I have is the "http://localhost/" part.  I would like to be able to use a relative path instead of an absolute one so I don't have to update the link when I go live.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!  I ended up using a plug-in called Insert PHP.  That allowed me to put PHP code inside of the page.  Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you add that iframe but if is within the WordPress context you can use PHP

get_bloginfo

```
<iframe class="center-frame" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-content/weather/current.htm" width="750" height="1100"/>
```

The URL option returns the "Site address (URL)" set in Settings > General so when you go live that option will be change according with your settigs.

Comment: Thanks Enrique!  Unfortunately that did not work.  I am placing the statement directly into a Page using the text view.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you were placing the iframe code in WordPress php template, best approach will be what Enrique has already shared.

However as you are using Genesis, and you want to have the relative url in the WordPress posts text mode. I suggest you use Shortcode.

Use plugin like this for shortcodes:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-shortcodes/

And then use this short-code [wpurl], [url], [site_url] or whichever suits you.

Hope it helps.